# Asynchronous calls to load data and get notified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When users submit a form I need to get data from 5 different sources. Once data from those 5 is loaded I need to perform some validation.

If I wait for each of them to be loaded before proceeding to next one, it is taking way too long. I want to make all these calls asynchronous and once all of them are loaded would like to get notified and proceed with my validation. How can I achieve this? I have the method this way:

```
public void Submit()
{
    var sqlData1 = GetSqlData(1, DateTime.Now.ToString(), 0, 1);
    var sqlData2 = GetSqlData(2, DateTime.Now.ToString(), 0, 1);
    var sqlData3 = GetSqlData(3, DateTime.Now.ToString(), 0, 1);
    var sqlData4 = GetSqlData(4, DateTime.Now.ToString(), 0, 1);
    var sqlData5 = GetSqlData(5, DateTime.Now.ToString(), 0, 1);

    //Once all data is loaded perform my validation here
}



public List<sqlData> GetSqlData(int dataType, string dateTime, int getLatest, int getArchived)
{
    var sqldata = new List<sqlData>();                

    DbCommandWrapper = Db.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper("sp_loadData");
    //add Params
    var dataSet = Db.ExecuteDataSet(DbCommandWrapper);
    return sqlData;
}
```

Comment: Please show `GetSqlData`, is that function asynchronous or synchronous (Does it return `Task<SomeType>` or `SomeType`)? We also need to see it because `GetSqlData` may not be thread safe if you are reusing connections across calls.

Comment: Added the GetSqlData above. All the methods make call to same database and get data from same table but with different type.

Comment: See, I wanted to see how you made the actual database call. Now I know your method is synchronous, and the best option would be make the database calls asynchronous but I can't show you how to do it if you don't show how you are making the database calls. I also wanted to see if you where reusing `SqlConnection` objects or if you where making a new one per request.

Comment: We use microsoft application blocks that will create connection per call basis, i dont explicitly specify any connection. All the connection happen in base class. Its too big of a class to copy here, hope i answered you question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how you're fetching your data, I would recommend using `async` and `await` with `Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`, as `WaitAll` will still block threads. Obviously this has not been tested but should get you close to what you are looking for.

```
public async Task Submit() 
{
    int[] ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var sqlList = new List<sqlData>();

    sqlList.Add(await Task.WhenAll(ids.Select(i => GetSqlData(i, DateTime.Now.ToString(), 0, 1))));
}

public async Task<List<sqlData>> GetSqlData(int dataType, string dateTime, int getLatest, int getArchived)
{
    var sqldata = new List<sqlData>();
    // populate sqldata here - make sure you use an await call
    // make sure the method in your base call is updated to be async full-stack
    return sqldata;
}
```

[How and Where Concurrent Asynchronous I/O with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-and-where-concurrent-asynchronous-io-with-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Without examples or explination how to make it async I doubt he will correctly change `GetSqlData` to be async, likely the OP will copy your code verbatim and just do `async` without having any `await` inside `GetSqlData` and the class will just run exactly the same as before.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottChamberlain. Yeah, I was hoping that the pattern in the answer, along with the link I provided would allow him to get the gist of asynchronous programming. As I said (believe you did as well), without seeing how he's fetching the data (meaning, without seeing that base class OP is referring to), I can't give a *complete* answer. He will need to make that base class method async and await the call(s) full stack. But hopefully the horse is lead to water.